# Convert array of strings to array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a jQuery array `["3434", "3433"]`

And I would like to make it like `[3434, 3433]`

Comment: `["3434", "3433"].map(Number)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for jQuery. Supposing you're sure they're all numbers (that is, we're not checking for errors), you can `map` them with `Number`, which converts them from string to numbers.

```
["3434", "3433"].map(Number);
```

Considering that `Number` returns `NaN` in case of error, you may then want to `filter` the result to remove undesired elements.

```js
let nums = ["3434", "3433", "foo"].map(Number).filter(n => !isNaN(n));
console.log(nums);
```